# Getting the inserted rows to update another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which stores records which require to be inserted into another database. Once these values are inserted, I then need to mark these records as processed to prevent them being re-processed.

```
DECLARE @InsertedValues TABLE (
    [ITEMNMBR] nchar(31),
    [ITEMDESC] nchar(101),
    [ITMSHNAM] nchar(15),
    [ITMGEDSC] nchar(11),
    [UOMSCHDL] nchar(11),
    [ALTITEM1] nchar(31),
    [ALTITEM2] nchar(31),
    [USCATVLS_1] nchar(11),
    [USCATVLS_2] nchar(11),
    [USCATVLS_3] nchar(11),
    [USCATVLS_6] nchar(11),
    [ABCCODE] int,
    [ROW_ID] int
)

-- INSERT NEW INVENTORY ITEMS INTO DB
INSERT INTO TABLE1..IV00101 (ITEMNMBR,ITEMDESC,ITMSHNAM,ITMGEDSC,UOMSCHDL,ALTITEM1,ALTITEM2,USCATVLS_1,USCATVLS_2,USCATVLS_3,USCATVLS_6,ABCCODE)
OUTPUT          
    INSERTED.[ITEMNMBR],
    INSERTED.[ITEMDESC],
    INSERTED.[ITMSHNAM],
    INSERTED.[ITMGEDSC],
    INSERTED.[UOMSCHDL],
    INSERTED.[ALTITEM1],
    INSERTED.[ALTITEM2],
    INSERTED.[USCATVLS_1],
    INSERTED.[USCATVLS_2],
    INSERTED.[USCATVLS_3],
    INSERTED.[USCATVLS_6],
    INSERTED.[ABCCODE],
    U.[ROW_ID] INTO @InsertedValues
SELECT U.[ITEMNMBR],U.[ITEMDESC],U.[ITMSHNAM],U.[ITMGEDSC],U.[UOMSCHDL],U.[ALTITEM1],U.[ALTITEM2],U.[USCATVLS_1],U.[USCATVLS_2],U.[USCATVLS_3],U.[USCATVLS_6],U.[ABCCODE]
FROM 
    DYNAMICS..TABLE2 AS U
WHERE 
    U.[ProcessedFlag] = 0 AND 
    U.[Action] = 'I' AND 
    U.[DestinationCompany] = 'COMPANY1' AND
    U.[DestinationTable] = 'IV00101'
```

As it stands currently, this query doesn't work as it complains about the U.[ROW_ID] column in the OUTPUT statement which makes sense. So my problem is, how do I get the row that was inserted so that I can then run the following query?

```
UPDATE DYNAMICS..TABLE2
SET [ProcessedFlag] = 1, [ProcessedDateTime] = GETDATE()
FROM @InsertedValues AS U
    INNER JOIN DYNAMICS..TABLE2 AS R ON U.[ROW_ID] = R.[ROW_ID]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd consider using eConnect, since messing with GP tables is not a good idea (though inserting into IV00101 should be OK since it's inventory master ... but still!)

What version of GP are you using? GP10 and GP2010 support webservices which have methods which allow you to insert an inventory item, otherwise you can use eConnect and provide XML files to the eConnect entrypoint which it will process. It also provides validation and error handling. You can use message queuing too if needs be

Are you trying to do an import from your own holding table into the GP tables or something like that?

I do plenty of GP and integration where I work :)

Comment: We have 4/5 companies in our GP10 instance. I'm setting this up so that one company becomes the master for certain inventory fields. Any new items added or updates to those fields in the "master" company db results in the changes being pushed to the other companies. So they don't have to keep the item masters up-to-date in 4/5 different companies.

Comment: Ah sounds ok to me - I'd probably still do it in eConnect just in case - I assume you have created a separate table for tracking which items have been processed? Upgrades can change the DB structure so I wouldn't recommend changing the original tables.

Comment: I'd probably SELECT all items that haven't been processed yet into a table variable, then UPDATE them all to set them to processed. Then you can work from your table variable, and on errors, reset the flag on each record (or do it the opposite way and don't update them until you are sure they have been done). Either way, I recommend creating a separate table for the tracking as a GP2010 upgrade may change IV00101 on the databases. Always best to be future proof eh!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the number of updated rows with standard SQL, but probably any database allows to do it. Bit it won't be that easy to help you, if you don't tell what RDBMS are you using and where are you calling the SQL instructions from. I mean a script executed on what db client application or an application you're developing in T-SQL, PL-SQL, pgplsql, java, PHP, c/c++, c#, VB or whatever language you should say, probably using a db-library you should also say.

Comment: Those strange brackets `[]` clearly indicate a Microsoft database.

Comment: It's a Microsoft Dynamics GP database

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DYNAMICS..TABLE2
SET [ProcessedFlag] = 1, [ProcessedDateTime] = GETDATE()
WHERE
    DYNAMICS..TABLE2.[ProcessedFlag] = 0 AND 
    DYNAMICS..TABLE2.[Action] = 'I' AND 
    DYNAMICS..TABLE2.[DestinationCompany] = 'COMPANY1' AND
    DYNAMICS..TABLE2.[DestinationTable] = 'IV00101'
```

Just update the same set of records you selected in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion. You should use identity columns when you have similar kind of scenarios. Since after that use of  `@@IDENTITY/SCOPE_IDENTITY()` becomes pretty easy.
Anyways, I'll suggest you to use trigger if this table doesn't have multiple insertions simultaneously as triggers have a few disadvantages of there own.